# Java EE: @ApplicationException thrown, still rolls back transactions

Tags: exception, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

I need some direction how to best use Exceptions in a Java EE environment, serving clients via JAX-RS.

At the moment, I have a number of exceptions, all extending `RuntimeException`, and annotated with `@ApplicationException(rollback=false)`. In order to transport them to the clients, they carry a JAXB-annotated entity; and an `ExceptionMapper` is ready to convert them to proper, meaningful HTTP Responses (HTTP Status codes included).

I have nothing specified regarding transactional behaviour, so I guess it defaults to CMT.

Great stuff so far: when the server decides, it cannot fulfill a request, because input data is not valid/sufficient/whatever, it throws one of my `BadRequestException`, which makes it to the JAX-RS resource, where it gets mapped to a HTTP Response. Client is informed about what went wrong.

**The issue** I have is that I always get a `javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException`, caused by `BadRequestException`! I don't want the transaction to be rolled back! The @ApplicationException seems to be ignored...

Should I not extend from `RuntimeException` but rather use checked exceptions? I though @ApplicationException was supposed to be the right way...

For background information: all of my Exceptions leave the container/beans in a working state. No need for the bean instance to be destroyed or stuff like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, turns out reading the manuals *does* help sometimes :).

An `@ApplicationException` is by definition **not** a `RuntimeException`. In fact, throwing `RuntimeExceptions` seems to be a very bad idea, that's what'll tear down a bean instance, rollback transactions, etc.

After switching everything to be based on **checked Exceptions**, my code not only looks much better, the IDE supports me much better as well. And it works like a charm. Now I can control, if my `ApplicationException` should cause transaction rollback or not.

I found [this link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13226_01/workshop/docs81/doc/en/core/index.html) useful, even though it describes it for Bea Weblogic.

Comment: EJB 3.1 spec, section 14.2.1: "An application exception that is an unchecked exception is defined as an application exception by annotating it with the ApplicationException metadata annotation, or denoting it in the deployment descriptor with the application-exception element."

Comment: Thanks. Strange that Glassfish 3.1 does not follow the specification then.

Comment: This answer is just not true and contains wrong information. From the EJB spec quoted by bkail a bit longer quote: "Application exceptions that are checked exceptions may be defined as such by being listed in the throws clauses of the methods of the bean’s businessinterface, no-interface view, home interface, component interface, and web service endpoint. An application exception that is an unchecked exception is defined as an application exception by annotating it with the ApplicationException metadata annotation."

Answer (score 4):

For others struggling with same problem:
Annotation @ApplicationException is ignored(Not scanned/not processed) when Exception class is not included in ejb-jar. That is a common case when our ApplicationException is a part of API jar. In that case we have to use XML descriptor to mark ApplicationException.

Looking here helped me -> https://www.java.net//node/665096

Comment: That was very helpful.  You might want to know this was filed as a bug that was fixed in GF3: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-5183

Comment: I encountered the same problem with wildfly 10.0 Final. When an exception was in a different application and different EJB that exception did not cause rollback(commited). When I moved it it worked fine.